# How to test in Clojure if any given value is not-empty collection?

Tags: clojure

I need a predicate which returns logically true if the given value is a not-empty collection and logically false if it's anything else (number, string etc.).
And more specifically, that the predicate won't throw the `IllegalArgumentException` if applied to single number, or string.

I came up with the following function, but I'm wondering if **there is some more idiomatic approach?**

```clj
(defn not-empty-coll? [x]
  (and (coll? x) (seq x)))
```

This will satisfy following tests:

```clj
(is (not (not-empty-coll? nil)))    ;; -> false
(is (not (not-empty-coll? 1)))      ;; -> false
(is (not (not-empty-coll? "foo")))  ;; -> false
(is (not (not-empty-coll? [])))     ;; -> nil      (false)
(is (not (not-empty-coll? '())))    ;; -> nil      (false)
(is (not (not-empty-coll? {})))     ;; -> nil      (false)
(is (not-empty-coll? [1]))          ;; -> (1)      (true)
(is (not-empty-coll? '(1)))         ;; -> (1)      (true)
(is (not-empty-coll? {:a 1}))       ;; -> ([:a 1]) (true)
```

EDIT: A potential use case:

Let's say we need to process some raw external data which are not (yet) under our control. Input could be for example a collection which contains either primitive values, or nested collections. Other example could be a collection holding some inconsistent (maybe broken?) tree structure. So, we can consider mentioned predicate as first line data cleaning.

Otherwise, I agree with comments that is better to explicitly separate and process collection and non-collection data.

Comment: Have you tried [empty?](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/empty_q)?

Comment: Yes, but ``empty`` can be used on collections only. It throws an exception if used on number: ``(empty? 1)``.

Comment: Honestly, I think it's more common to just be aware when you're calling the function of whether you have a collection or scalar type. Then you don't need to mash both cases together like this.

Comment: `seq` (hence `not-empty-coll?`) returns `nil` on empty collections and itself on a non-empty collection: `(map not-empty-coll? [() [42]]) => (nil (42))`. If you want `false` and `true` values, convert to boolean: `(defn not-empty-coll? [x] (and (coll? x) (boolean (seq x))))`, giving `(map not-empty-coll? [() [42]]) => (false true)`

Comment: Yes, I know about `(boolean (seq x))` idiom, but for my need it was enough to have predicate where `nil` is equivalent of `false`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I would consider calling `not-empty?` with a non-collection argument to be an invalid usage, which should generate an `IllegalArgumentException`.

There is already a function `not-empty?` available for use [in the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).  Here are the unit tests:

```
(deftest t-not-empty
  (is (every?      not-empty? ["one" [1] '(1) {:1 1} #{1}     ] ))
  (is (has-none?   not-empty? [ ""   [ ] '( ) {}     #{ }  nil] ))

  (is= (map not-empty? ["1" [1] '(1) {:1 1} #{1} ] )
         [true true true true true]  )
  (is= (map not-empty? ["" [] '() {} #{} nil] )
         [false false false false false false ] )

  (is= (keep-if not-empty?  ["1" [1] '(1) {:1 1} #{1} ] )
                            ["1" [1] '(1) {:1 1} #{1} ] )
  (is= (drop-if not-empty?  [""  []  '()  {}     #{}  nil] )
                            [""  []  '()  {}     #{}  nil] )

  (throws? IllegalArgumentException (not-empty? 5))
  (throws? IllegalArgumentException (not-empty? 3.14)))
```

---

## Update

The preferred approach would be for a function to only receive collection parameters in a given argument, not a mixture scalar & collection arguments. Then, one only needs `not-empty` given the pre-knowledge that the value in question is not a scalar.  [I often use Plumatic Schema](https://github.com/plumatic/schema) to enforce this assumption and catch any errors in the calling code:

```
(ns xyz
  (:require [schema.core :as s] )) ; plumatic schema
(s/defn foo :- [s/Any]
  "Will do bar to the supplied collection"
  [coll :- [s/Any]]
  (if (not-empty coll)
    (mapv bar foo)
    [ :some :default :value ] ))
```

The 2 uses of notation `:- [s/Any]` checks that the arg & return value are both declared to be a sequential collection (list or vector). Each element is unrestricted by the `s/Any` part.

---

If you can't enforce the above strategy for some reason, I would just modify your first approach as follows:

```
(defn not-empty-coll? [x]
  (and (coll? x) (t/not-empty? x)))
```

I'm hoping you know at least a little about the param `x` so the question becomes: Is x a scalar or a non-empty vector.  Then you could say something like:

```
(defn not-empty-coll? [x]
  (and (sequential? x) (t/not-empty? x)))
```

Comment: _Tupelo_ looks like a nice library, but suggested `not-empty?` function still doesn't satisfy my needs - it throws an exception for numbers.

Comment: Every function has assumptions and/or restrictions on what constitute valid inputs. For example, you can multiply 2 numbers but not 2 strings. The remainer of dividing 2 integers is well-defined but makes no sense if dividing to real numbers. The length given by `(count ...)` makes sense for collections (list, vector, etc), but not for  a number:  `(count 5)` is an invalid question.  Similarly, a number like `5` is neither empty nor not-empty since it is unable to contain anything in the first place!

Comment: I agree. Assumptions and constraints on functions make sense. But then, how to treat the use case described in the question?

Answer (score 0):

How about using Clojure protocols and type extensions to solve this?

```
(defprotocol EmptyCollPred
  (not-empty-coll? [this]))

(extend-protocol EmptyCollPred
  Object
    (not-empty-coll? [this] false)
  nil
    (not-empty-coll? [this] false)
  clojure.lang.Seqable
    (not-empty-coll? [this] (not (empty? (seq this)))))

(is (not (not-empty-coll? nil)))    ;; -> false
(is (not (not-empty-coll? 1)))      ;; -> false
(is (not (not-empty-coll? "foo")))  ;; -> false
(is (not (not-empty-coll? [])))     ;; -> nil      (false)
(is (not (not-empty-coll? '())))    ;; -> nil      (false)
(is (not (not-empty-coll? {})))     ;; -> nil      (false)
(is (not-empty-coll? [1]))          ;; -> (1)      (true)
(is (not-empty-coll? '(1)))         ;; -> (1)      (true)
(is (not-empty-coll? {:a 1}))       ;; -> ([:a 1]) (true)
```

Maybe it would be cleaner to extend just `String` and `Number` instead of `Object` - depends on what do you know about the incoming data. Also, it would be probably better to filter out `nil`s beforehand instead of creating a case for it as you see above.

Another - conceptually similar - solution could use multimethods.

Comment: The idea of the usage of *protocols* is interesting. Just maybe, too big overhead? Nevertheless, I'm not sure, how much it is *idiomatic*. For me, it smells like Java polymorphism. But probably I'm biased because I came from that background.